# Refreshing JEditorPane with new data

Tags: java, swing, executorservice, jeditorpane

I am trying to refresh JEditorPane every 5 seconds if new data added to database table it should get reflected, But its not repainting.

Firstly i have a JFrame which is as below which is called inside a constructor

```
public Browser(String initialURL) {  

    this.initialURL = initialURL;
    WindowUtilities.setNativeLookAndFeel();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    urlField = new JTextField(30);
    getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

    try {
        htmlPane = new JEditorPane(initialURL);
        htmlPane.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(htmlPane);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
       warnUser("Can't build HTML pane for " + initialURL 
                + ": " + ioe);
    }

    Dimension screenSize = getToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds(400, 300, 600, 400);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

For launching this i have created one singlton class as below and passing url of xhtml page to be loaded which picks the data from database.

```
public class BrowserInstance {

    public static Browser browser ;

    public static synchronized Browser getInstance(String serverpath)
    {
        if(browser == null)
        {
            browser = new Browser(serverpath);
        }
        else if(browser != null)
        {
            try {
                browser.getHtmlPane().setEditable(false);
                browser.setVisible(true);
                browser.getHtmlPane().setPage(serverpath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return browser;
    }

}
```

But for some reason its not refreshing page inside popup . I'm able to call this singlton class every 5 second using ScheduledExecutorService concept your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're passing the same `url` as the one which is currently displayed by the `EditorPane`, the document will not be reloaded. So you have to force the document reload by clearing the `stream description property` of the document  (see [setPage()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage(java.net.URL)) method).

You have just to add the following code :

```
Document document = browser.getHtmlPane().getDocument();
document.putProperty(Document.StreamDescriptionProperty, null);
```

Comment: Hi @blackbishop i added this code before setpage() to else part of getInstance(String serverpath) no errors, But it displaces blank page.

Comment: @pravi Have you tried to add it after the `setPage()` ?

Comment: @pravi also make sure the page is not empty

Comment: @blackbishop code is invoked from ScheduledExecutorService, then it can has an issue with EDT, can be caused by blank page, really depends of ..., no idea without an MCVE/SSCCE

Comment: I tried to add after setPage() but no luck, and i'm sure the page is not empty . And its not displaying anything except white page not even the xhtml page. When i use this.But its hitting the server i'm able to check with few SOP statements.